What algorithm does z3prover ueses to decide the consistency of a set of sentences?
Hi I learned a little bit of first order logic and want to understand  z3prover.
With my understanding, for a set of axioms if there is a model can satisfy them then they are consistent by Godel's completeness theorem.
However, the possibility of model is usually unlimited, how does z3 solve the unlimited possibility??
I've searched the net and cannot find detailed illustration of what algorithm it uses.
If anyone is nice enough to give me some guide to understand the reasons lie behind it? thanks a lot!

See the model-constructing satisfiability (mcSAT) procedure
